# Django 1.10 doesn't show post from db

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm learning django framework writing a blog. I've added some posts in django-admin and I want to show them on web.

**MODELS.PY**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager,
                     self).get_queryset()\
                    .filter(status='published')


class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Roboczy'),
        ('publish', 'Opublikowany')
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300, unique_for_date='publish')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default='draft')
    object = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                       args=[self.publish.year,
                             self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                             self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                             self.slug])
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.published.all()
    return render(request,
                  'blog/post/list.html',
                  {'posts': posts})


def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
                             status ='published',
                             publish_year=year,
                             publish_month=month,
                             publish_day=day)
    return render(request,
                  'blog/post/detail.html',
                  {'post': post})
```

**URLS.PY** at BLOG APP

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/$'
        r'(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.post_detail,
        name='post_detail'),
]
```

**URLS.PY** (project level)

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls',
                         namespace='blog',
                         app_name='blog')),


]
```

**list.html**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %}My Blog {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Mój BLOG</h1>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <h2>
            <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
                {{ post.title }}
            </a>
        </h2>
        <p>
            Opublikowane {{ post.publish }} przez {{ post.author }}
        </p>
        {{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I don't know why these posts aren't shown on list.html. I think the mistake is in get_absolute_url.

Comment: It would be useful to know the error you're getting. Does it show an empty page or some django related error?

Comment: Please try to create an [mcve], its pretty clear that your question has nothing to do with a `PublishManager` class, or the url patterns for admin etc

Comment: @AndreaConte i have empty page.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`posts = Post.published.all()`

Try

```
posts = Post.objects.all()
```

Comment: if i change to objects i have erro to no exsist but when i change to obiect i have this error

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /blog/

Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '(2016, '12', '20', 'post-numer3')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<year>\\d{4})/(?P<month>\\d{2})/(?P<day>\\d{2})/$(?P<post>[-\\w]+)/$']

Comment: No i think i must change post.get_absolute_url

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's work i must change posts = Post.objects.all() and  on list.htlm

```
<a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
```

to

```
<a href="{{ posts }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Urlpatterns are wrong.

```
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/$'
    r'(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
    views.post_detail,
    name='post_detail'),
```

According to the views the url pattern should be:

```
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
    views.post_detail,
    name='post_detail'),
```

Also, Views are wrong:

```
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
                             status ='published',
                             publish__year=year,
                             publish__month=month,
                             publish__day=day)
    return render(request,
                  'blog/post/detail.html',
                  {'post': post})
```

Please note that query fields are **publish__year** (not publish_year), **publish___month**(not publish_month) and **publish__date**( not publish_date)

Once you make these changes, the get_absolute_url will also work fine.
I don't know if you want to use `Post.objects.all()` or `Post.published.all()`. Ideally, it should be `Post.published.all()` because in general, only published posts are displayed.